# How to convert wiki-link images to normal md-link images using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, markdown

I have some markdown files containing images in `![[image_links]]` a.k.a wiki-link format. I want to convert them into `![image_name](image_link)` a.k.a standard markdown image format. I am using python3 for the conversion.

I've used [WikiLinks extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/wikilinks/), but it doesn't give any satisfactory result. How can I convert them using python 3.x?

I have used regex to find the string as follows:

```
import re

txt = "The ![[12345]] ![[12345.jpg]] ![[Pasted image 20210519063449.png]] ha ![[Test.jpeg]] haha quick brown 123.45 fox [[jumps]]"
pattern = re.compile(r'!\[\[\D*\d*\.\D{3,4}]]')
print(pattern.findall(txt))
```

But how to replace them using regex or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
r'!\[\[(?:(http[^\]]+)|([^\]]+)(\.\D{3,4}))\]\]'
```

Details:

- `!\[\[` - a literal `![[` string
- `(?:` - Non-capturing group

  - `(` - Group 1:
  - `http[^\]]+` - literal `http` follow by any char other than a `]` one or more times
  - `)` - close 1st capturing group
- `|` - or

  - `([^\]]+)` - Group 2: any char other than a `]` one or more times, follow by
  - `(\.\D{3,4})` - Group 3: a literal `.` follow by 3 or 4 of any char other than a digit
- `)` - close non-capturing group
- `\]\]` - a literal `]]` string

```py
import re

txt = "The ![[12345]] ![[12345.jpg]] ![[Pasted image 20210519063449.png]] ha ![[Test.jpeg]] haha quick brown 123.45 fox [[jumps]] ![[http://example/images/image1.webp]]"

pattern = re.compile(r'!\[\[(?:(http[^\]]+)|([^\]]+)(\.\D{3,4}))\]\]')
match = pattern.findall(txt)
for m in match:
    if m[0]: # http link
        print(f'![{m[0]}]({m[0]})')
    else:
        print(f'![{m[1]}]({m[1]}{m[2]})')
```

```markdown
![12345](12345.jpg)
![Pasted image 20210519063449](Pasted image 20210519063449.png)
![Test](Test.jpeg)
![http://example/images/image1.webp](http://example/images/image1.webp)
```